# Node and crontab not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am trying to run an node script with crontab but its not working as I expected (Ubuntu 12.04). In my crontab file I got

`*/1   * * * *     node /home/me/path/to/script.js > /home/me/path/to/output`

This produces **empty string output** while it shouldn't.

When I run `node /home/me/path/to/script.js > /home/me/path/to/output` though, manually, everything goes fine.

Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Try changing `node` to what comes from `which node`. That is, put full path of binary executing process.

Comment: Also, make sure your crontab script runs as `me` and not `www-data` or something similar.

Comment: as @fedorqui said, use the absolute path. This is not only for Node, you should always use absolute paths with `crontab`. Explanation here: http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html

Comment: @fedorqui, you should post as an answer.  Paris should not get credit for your answer...

Comment: Thanks, @Jessemon, I will do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cronjob does not execute a script that works fine standalone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885909/cronjob-does-not-execute-a-script-that-works-fine-standalone)

Answer (score 4):

Change `node` to what comes from `which node`. That is, put full path of the binary executing process.

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/node /home/me/path/to/script.js > /home/me/path/to/output
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The value is normally something like `/usr/bin/node`.

Comment: Does */1 run every minute?  Great to learn something new every day!

Comment: Yes! In fact I recently looked for information on very equivalent expressions to write in crontab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853793/is-these-cron-expressions-equivalent/15441278#15441278